# CROSS Join is not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

see the output which i am trying to generate by SQL with dummy data
[image]

this is my sql which is throwing error **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
    CallStar datetime,
    Direction char(1),
    PartyName varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('20150609 08:02:51','I','VM Channel 1'),
('20150609 08:04:14','I','VM Channel 1'),
('20150609 08:35:51','O','VM Channel 1'),
('20150609 08:40:14','O','VM Channel 1'),

('20150609 08:02:51','I','VM Channel 2'),
('20150609 08:04:14','I','VM Channel 2'),
('20150609 08:35:51','O','VM Channel 2'),
('20150609 08:40:14','O','VM Channel 2'),
('20150609 08:04:14','O','ACC'),
('20150609 08:04:14','I','ACC'),
('20150609 08:04:14','I','ACC')

DECLARE     @StartTime datetime = '2015-06-09 09:00:00',
            @EndTime datetime = '2015-06-09 18:00:00',
            @Interval int = 30 -- this can be changed.


;WITH cSequence AS
(
    SELECT
       @StartTime AS StartRange, 
       DATEADD(MINUTE, @Interval, @StartTime) AS EndRange
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      EndRange, 
      DATEADD(MINUTE, @Interval, EndRange)
    FROM cSequence 
    WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, @Interval, EndRange) < @EndTime
)



SELECT
    PartyName,
    DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,CallStar) / 30 * 30, 0) AS "DateStart",
    DATEADD(minute, 30, DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, CallStar) / 30 * 30, 0)) AS "DateEnd",
    SUM(CASE WHEN Direction = 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Incoming",
    SUM(CASE WHEN Direction = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Outgoing",
    SUM(CASE WHEN Direction = 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Transfer"
FROM @t CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM cSequence) s
GROUP BY
    PartyName,
    DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,CallStar) / 30 * 30, 0)
ORDER BY    
    PartyName,
    DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,CallStar) / 30 * 30, 0)
```

where i am making the mistake for which cross join is not applying?

### EDIT 1

For Incoming data calculation

```
where direction='I' and   
Is_Internal=0 and continuation=0 and   
RIGHT(convert(varchar,[call duration]),8)<> '00:00:00'
```

For outgoing data calculation

```
where direction='O' 
and Is_Internal=0 and continuation=0
```

For outgoing data calculation

```
where continuation=1     
and RIGHT(convert(varchar,[call duration]),8)<> '00:00:00'
```

For misscall data calculation

```
where direction='I' and   
RIGHT(convert(varchar,[call duration]),8)= '00:00:00' and [Ring duration]>0
```

just see and tell me can i add more clause here as below

```
SUM(CASE WHEN (Direction = 'I' AND Is_Internal=0 AND continuation=0 AND   
RIGHT(convert(varchar,[call duration]),8)<> '00:00:00') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Incoming",

SUM(CASE WHEN (Direction = 'O' AND Is_Internal=0 AND continuation=0     
) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Outgoing"
```

### EDIT 2

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(CallStar datetime, Direction char(1), PartyName varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('2015-06-09 08:02:51','I','VM Channel 1'),
('2015-06-09 08:04:14','I','VM Channel 1'),
('2015-06-09 08:02:51','O','VM Channel 1'),
('2015-06-09 08:02:51','I','VM Channel 1'),
('2015-06-09 08:34:14','I','VM Channel 1'),
('2015-06-09 18:02:51','I','VM Channel 1'),
('2015-06-09 18:04:14','I','VM Channel 1'),
('2015-06-09 18:02:51','O','VM Channel 1'),
('2015-06-09 18:02:51','T','VM Channel 1'),

('2015-06-09 01:02:51','I','VM Channel 2'),
('2015-06-09 02:04:14','I','VM Channel 2'),
('2015-06-09 03:02:51','O','VM Channel 2'),
('2015-06-09 04:02:51','I','VM Channel 2'),
('2015-06-09 05:34:14','I','VM Channel 2'),
('2015-06-09 16:02:51','I','VM Channel 2'),
('2015-06-09 17:04:14','I','VM Channel 2'),
('2015-06-09 18:02:51','O','VM Channel 2'),
('2015-06-09 19:02:51','T','VM Channel 2')

;WITH times AS (
SELECT CAST('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) AS time, 0 AS sortSeq
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,30,time) AS time, sortSeq + 1 AS sortSeq
  FROM times
 WHERE CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,30,time) AS DATE) = CAST(time AS DATE)
), 

final AS (
SELECT PartyName, DateStar, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,time) / 30 * 30, 0),108),5) 
+ ' - ' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(minute, 30, DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, time) / 30 * 30, 0)),108),5) AS groupName, sortSeq
  FROM times
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT PartyName, CAST(callStar AS DATE) AS dateStar
                   FROM @t
                ) a
) 

SELECT f.PartyName, f.DateStar, f.GroupName, COALESCE(t.Incoming,0) AS Incoming, COALESCE(t.Outgoing,0) AS Outgoing, COALESCE(t.Transfer,0) AS Transfer
  FROM final f
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                     SELECT PartyName, CAST(CallStar AS DATE) AS DateStar, 
                     LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,CallStar) / 30 * 30, 0),108),5) 
                     + ' - ' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(minute, 30, DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, CallStar) / 30 * 30, 0)),108),5) AS groupName,  
                     DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,CallStar) / 30 * 30, 0) AS DateStart,    
                     DATEADD(minute, 30, DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, CallStar) / 30 * 30, 0)) AS DateEnd, 
                     SUM(CASE WHEN Direction = 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Incoming, 
                     SUM(CASE WHEN Direction = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Outgoing, 
                     SUM(CASE WHEN Direction = 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Transfer
                       FROM @t t
                      GROUP BY PartyName, CAST(CallStar AS DATE), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,CallStar) / 30 * 30, 0)
                     ) t
      ON f.PartyName = t.PartyName
      AND f.groupName = t.groupName
      AND f.dateStar = t.dateStar
 ORDER BY f.PartyName, f.DateStar, f.sortSeq
```

Comment: You don't need a subquery here. Just a simple cross join. FROM @t CROSS JOIN cSequence s

Comment: Have you tried with `CROSS APPLY`?

Comment: Are you sure that is the sql you are running?? I copied and pasted into my local and it runs just fine.

Comment: Your code gets no error in SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd157.

Comment: i know code is not giving error but no giving the result like cross join...where is the mistake?

Comment: @SeanLange i tried `FROM @t CROSS Apply cSequence s` cross apply is not giving right result.

Comment: So your code is throwing the error message you stated or it isn't producing the results you want? Your question is not very clear. What do you expect as output from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all time slots for all parties you need to do a cross join on the ranges and parties, and then use a left join to fill in the actual data.

I think this is what you want:

```
with cSequence as (
....
)

SELECT
    s.StartRange, s.EndRange,
    s.PartyName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Direction = 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Incoming",
    SUM(CASE WHEN Direction = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Outgoing",
    SUM(CASE WHEN Direction = 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Transfer"

-- this is what changed
FROM (SELECT * FROM cSequence CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT PARTYNAME FROM @T) p) S
LEFT JOIN @t t ON s.StartRange = DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,CallStar) / 30 * 30, 0) 
              AND s.EndRange = DATEADD(minute, 30, DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, CallStar) / 30 * 30, 0))
              AND t.PartyName = s.PartyName
GROUP BY
    s.PartyName,
    s.StartRange,s.EndRange, 
    DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,CallStar) / 30 * 30, 0)
ORDER BY    
    s.PartyName,
    s.StartRange,s.EndRange,    
    DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,CallStar) / 30 * 30, 0)
    ;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2793)

I left out the temp table and cte and only included the last select.

The query can most likely be improved a bit, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: tell me Cross Join and Cross Apply is same or produce different output ?

Comment: @Mou `cross join` and `cross apply` are not the same, and they produce different output. A `cross join` creates a cartesian product of two sets (that is, all possible combinations, in your case between the ranges and the parties), while a `cross apply` functions more like an `inner join` (often used to apply a function or something similar to a set).

Comment: can u plzz redirect me to right article on cross apply which describe it with very easy example.....so i can understand in what kind of situation people should go for cross apply clause. thanks

Comment: @Mou This article seems fairly good: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607246/Making-OUTER-and-CROSS-APPLY-work-for-you And of course the product documentation is a good source with some examples.

Comment: please see my edit portion and come with your suggestion. thanks

Comment: @Mou Yes, you should be able to add those case expressions instead of the ones you have.

Comment: here i add my edit 2 section where i paste another solution for same output but the difference is they use cross apply clause instead of cross join. please have a look and give your comments.

Comment: @Mou Yes, that seems to be a working solution too. Might perform better too.

Comment: why do you think that is better. please tell me because i like to know and that help to increase my knowledge. thanks

Comment: i posted a working version as answer. have a look if u like.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I ended up using. It's based on the SQL from jpw's answer (slightly adapted, as jpw's SQL did not return the data properly).

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME, @EndTime DATETIME
SELECT @StartTime = '09:00:00'
SELECT @EndTime = '17:30:00'

;WITH times AS (
SELECT CAST(@StartTime AS DATETIME) AS time, 0 AS sortSeq
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,30,time) AS time, sortSeq + 1 AS sortSeq
  FROM times
 WHERE time < @EndTime
)
, final AS (
SELECT Party1Name, DateStar, 
LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,time) / 30 * 30, 0),108),5) + ' - ' 
    + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(minute, 30, DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, time) / 30 * 30, 0)),108),5) AS groupName, 
    sortSeq   FROM times
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT Party1Name, CAST([call Start] AS DATE) AS dateStar
                   FROM CSRPhoneData_Interval
                ) a
) 

SELECT f.Party1Name as [CSR Name], f.GroupName as Time, COALESCE(t.Incoming,0) AS Incoming, 
    COALESCE(t.Outgoing,0) AS OutGoing, COALESCE(t.Transfer,0) AS [Call Transfer],COALESCE(t.misscall,0) AS MissCall
    FROM final f
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                     SELECT Party1Name, CAST([call Start] AS DATE) AS DateStar, 
                        LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,[call Start]) / 30 * 30, 0),108),5) + ' - ' 
                            + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(minute, 30, DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, [call Start]) / 30 * 30, 0)),108),5) AS groupName,   
                            DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,[call Start]) / 30 * 30, 0) AS DateStart, 
                            DATEADD(minute, 30, DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, [call Start]) / 30 * 30, 0)) AS DateEnd, 
                            SUM(CASE WHEN (Direction = 'I' 
                                AND Is_Internal=0 
                                AND continuation=0 
                                AND RIGHT(convert(varchar,[call duration]),8)<> '00:00:00') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Incoming, 

                            SUM(CASE WHEN (Direction = 'O' AND Is_Internal=0 and continuation=0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Outgoing, 
                            SUM(CASE WHEN (Direction = 'T' 
                                AND continuation=1 
                                AND RIGHT(convert(varchar,[call duration]),8)<> '00:00:00') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Transfer,
                            SUM(CASE WHEN (Direction = 'I' 
                                AND RIGHT(convert(varchar,[call duration]),8)= '00:00:00' 
                                AND [Ring duration]>0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS misscall                               
                       FROM CSRPhoneData_Interval t
                      GROUP BY Party1Name, CAST([call Start] AS DATE), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,[call Start]) / 30 * 30, 0)
                     ) t
      ON f.Party1Name = t.Party1Name
      AND f.groupName = t.groupName
      AND f.dateStar = t.dateStar
 ORDER BY f.Party1Name, f.DateStar, f.sortSeq
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have two or more tables with the same structure

you could select the data this way:

```
Select * from 
(
Select Col_1,Col_2,Col_3 from Table_1 WHERE xxxx
UNION
Select Col_1,Col_2,Col_3 from Table_2 WHERE xxxx
UNION
Select Col_1,Col_2,Col_3 from Table_3 WHERE xxxx
) as NewTable
```

if you hate JOIN syntax